# Best way to constantly receive JSON and write to disk based on time period

Tags: go

I'm having difficulty coming up with a solution for constantly receiving JSON and appending it to a slice, then periodically based on a set time internal writing it to disk. I've come up with a solution however reading/writing to the same slice without any synchronization.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

type Message map[string]interface{}
type Messages []Message

var (
    messages Messages
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan Message)

    var messages Messages

    go func() {
        tick := time.Tick(200 * time.Millisecond)
        for {
            select {
            case <-tick:
                mb := []byte(`{ "glossary": { "title": "example glossary", "GlossDiv": { "title": "S", "GlossList": { "GlossEntry": { "ID": "SGML", "SortAs": "SGML", "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language", "Acronym": "SGML", "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986", "GlossDef": { "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.", "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"] }, "GlossSee": "markup" } } } } }`)
                var message Message
                json.Unmarshal(mb, &message)
                c <- message
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        tick := time.Tick(30 * time.Second)

        for {
            select {
            case <-tick:
                content, _ := json.Marshal(messages)
                now := time.Now().Unix()
                filename := "test" + strconv.FormatInt(now, 10) + ".json"
                err := ioutil.WriteFile(filename, content, 0644)
                if err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }

                messages = nil
            }
        }
    }()

    for {
        newmessage := <-c
        messages = append(messages, newmessage)
    }
}
```

Expecting 1 file per 30 seconds containing all messages received within last 30 seconds with no missed messages.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks good, except for the  synchronization piece:

```
var (
    messages Messages
    lock sync.Mutex
)

...
 newmessage := <-c
 lock.Lock()
 messages = append(messages, newmessage)
 lock.Unlock()
```

And for reading:

```
case <-tick:
    // Take a snapshot of messages, and reset it
    lock.Lock()
    msgs:=messages
    messages=Messages{}
    lock.Unlock()
    content, _ := json.Marshal(msgs)
    // No need for messages=nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that locks as little as possible and try to minimize allocations. It is also relatively simple and portable.

It uses a single select to avoid additional locking mechanism and write the json file async to prevent blocking of the consumer channel.

There is a dedicated json writer worker, that prevents an async call in the middle of the main select that would require additional JIT synchronization mechanism.

I also added the required mechanisms to finish the program properly (IE: close producer, drain consumer, drain messages, wait for flush on disk).

https://play.golang.org/p/5k3DgrceqKH

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Message map[string]interface{}
type Messages []Message

func main() {
    c := make(chan Message)

    go func() {
        tick := time.Tick(200 * time.Millisecond)
        s := make(chan os.Signal)
        signal.Notify(s)
        for {
            select {
            case <-s:
                close(c)
                return
            case <-tick:
                mb := []byte(`{ "glossary": { "title": "example glossary", "GlossDiv": { "title": "S", "GlossList": { "GlossEntry": { "ID": "SGML", "SortAs": "SGML", "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language", "Acronym": "SGML", "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986", "GlossDef": { "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.", "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"] }, "GlossSee": "markup" } } } } }`)
                var message Message
                json.Unmarshal(mb, &message)
                c <- message
            }
        }
    }()

    var msgPool = sync.Pool{
        New: func() interface{} {
            return Messages{}
        },
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    defer wg.Wait()
    cMessages := make(chan Messages)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for messages := range cMessages {
            log.Println("saved", len(messages), "messages")
            // content, _ := json.Marshal(messages)
            // now := time.Now().Unix()
            // filename := "test" + strconv.FormatInt(now, 10) + ".json"
            // err := ioutil.WriteFile(filename, content, 0644)
            // if err != nil {
            //     log.Println(err)
            // }
            msgPool.Put(messages)
        }
    }()

    messages := msgPool.Get().(Messages)
    save := time.Tick(1 * time.Second)
    for {
        select {
        case newmessage, ok := <-c:
            if !ok {
                <-save
                cMessages <- messages
                close(cMessages)
                return
            }
            messages = append(messages, newmessage)
        case <-save:
            cMessages <- messages

            messages = msgPool.Get().(Messages)
            messages = messages[:0]
        }
    }
}
```